# $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

While trying to use **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** I am getting *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"*. When I comment it out I do not get the error, but then I have "#" characters in the URL which I am trying to get rid of. I saw people reported some similar issues with ui.router which I do not use. In any case I was not able to find the solution from those posts. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

parserconfig.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='parserconfigApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <base href="file:///home/myusername/projects/parser_ui/">
    <title>Parser Config</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller='ParserConfigController as parserConfig'>

    <h1>Record Types</h1>

    <table style="font-size: medium; width: 50%; table-layout: fixed" ng-repeat='recordType in recordTypes'>
        <tr>
            <td><a>{{recordType}}</a></td>
            <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button><td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <a href="/addRecordType">Add</a>

</div>

<div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="parserconfigApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

parserconfigApp.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('parserconfigApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('ParserConfigController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.recordTypes = recordTypes;

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.recordTypes.splice(index, 1);
    }    

    $scope.changeView = function(view) {
        alert($location.path())
        $location.path(view);
        alert($location.path())        
    }
}]);

app.controller('AddRecordTypeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/addRecordType', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',
                controller: 'AddRecordTypeController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/addRecordType'
            });

            // use the HTML5 History API
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

var recordTypes = [
'Boot Record',
'Card Uptime Record',
'Stack Trace'
];
```

Comment: Could you make a plunkr /jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @Dan Pantry: Can jsfiddle handle AngularJS 1.3? I only see 1.2.

Comment: Yes. Codepen fiddle and plunkr all have options for it.

Comment: @Dan Pantry: What do I set <base href...> to here?

Comment: @jazzblue: `/`. It doesn't have to be an absolute path

Comment: @Dan Pantry: Thanks for the tips. I have created this example http://jsfiddle.net/jazzblue/h14Lgbd5/18/  , however it does not pick up the JS code. I thought that it should run the JS code by default. Am I doing anything wrong with jsfiddle?